# Why can't I catch error thrown from node-postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, error-handling, try-catch

I'm having an issue catching an error thrown from the Node-Postgres NPM package.

The issue seems simple on the surface, but I've tried everything I can think of.

My code is like the following:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg' // Import postgres connection pool
const pgPool = new Pool()

async function queryDatabase() {
  try {

    // Force TypeError by passing undefined
    let queryResult = await pgPool.query( undefined )

    if ( queryResult.rows.length > 0 ) {
      return queryResult.rows[0]
    }

    return false

  } catch( err ) {

    // Never Reached
    return new Error( 'Test error' )

  }
}
queryDatabase()
```

And the error is as follows:

> TypeError: Client was passed a null or undefined query
> at Client.query (~/.../node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:479:11)

The error itself is pretty self-explanatory. I'm forcing the error here, for the sake of trying to handle it in the event that `undefined` gets passed by mistake. I realize that I can simply perform a check to make sure the input is never null or undefined, but that's not my main concern.

My worry is if I can't catch this error thrown from this package, how many other unforeseen cases am I going to encounter where I simply can't catch and handle a thrown error.

I've tried numerous different approaches - The `Async/Await` `Try/Catch` method, shown above - I've tried  `pgPool.query().then().catch()` - Combinations of the two. I've even tried running the catch against the Pool instance itself. No matter what I do, I can't handle the exception without using Node's `process.on('unhandledRejection', ...)`, which is of course a bad idea.

I've been racking my brain on this for hours. Is there any way that I can catch and handle errors like this, so it's not crashing my server every time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831423/how-can-i-improve-error-handling-on-a-pool

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but that does not work. The pg package does not route this specific error through their error handler. They just throw it.

Comment: If passing `undefined` causes an exception that the above code does not catch, that's a bug. Please ensure you have the latest version of `pg`, then report the issue at github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this and it seems to be an actual bug in the `pg`-library.

According to the source if you call `.query` on a pool instance, this instance will [attempt to connect and get a client](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/2ef55503738eb2cbb6326744381a92c0bc0439ab/packages/pg-pool/index.js#L338). In this connect-callback the actual query is dispatched to the client-module, which will throw the mentioned type error [if the query is nil](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/80c500ffbffff8c2445dce44661e85590dc026e3/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L505).

This error is thrown synchronously (i.e. the error is **not** passed to the `callback` argument, e.g. `callback(new TypeError("...")`) and since there's no `try/catch` around the `client.query` call in the pool's connect-callback, the error will not be caught by your `try/catch`.

A potential fix would be to wrap the `client.query` call in a try catch:

```
 client.once('error', onError)
      this.log('dispatching query')
      try {
        client.query(text, values, (err, res) => {
          this.log('query dispatched')
          client.removeListener('error', onError)
          if (clientReleased) {
            return
          }
          clientReleased = true
          client.release(err)
          if (err) {
            return cb(err)
          } else {
            return cb(undefined, res)
          }
        })
      }catch(err) {
        return cb(err)
      }
```

So for now, you probably should create an issue on github and wait for the bugfix or fork the repo and use above workaround, I'm afraid.

Comment: I appreciate the response. It's unfortunate that it's an issue with the package. I suppose my confusion stemmed from not knowing that thrown errors wouldn't bubble up through the call stack. Seems rather inefficient.